# Why does ConstraintLayout peformance baddly on Samsung S6 and SamSung Galary S7

Tags: android, performance

I am doing some research on ConstarintLayout performance.Based on google official [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html),ConstraintLayout performance 40% better than Traditional Layout, however when I go on the same two xml file on SamSung S6 (SM-G9250) and Samsung S7(SM-G9300), it turns out ConstraintLayout performance baddly.Besides I test another devices, the result is same to the blog.Here it's my question, did samsung optimize performance on traditional layout ? or google's constraintlayout performace baddly on some system ?

Addition: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1 
I,m using.

Comment: Can you show us how did you find that?

Comment: I just have a phone SamSung S6,when I first tested the example , it's different from the result by official. After that, I tested the more devices.